# function is calling file specific values?

Tags: php

I have a very simple function in single.php file

```
<?php function file_nameecho(){
$fnam = basename(__FILE__, '.php'); 
echo $fnam;
}
?>
```

when calling this function in other.php file.

it is still showing the name of single.php file ?

Comment: *"it is still showing the name of single.php file ?"* - Is that a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you include the file with this function into another script and now you are wondering why the name is still the name from the script with the function and not the name where the function is called.

(So i think what you did:)

file1.php:

```
function file_nameecho() {
    $fnam = basename(__FILE__, '.php'); 
    echo $fnam;
}
```

file2.php:

```
include "file1.php";
file_nameecho();
```

Output would be:

```
file1.php
```

So that your function works like you want use this:

```
function file_nameecho(){
    $fnam = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '.php'); 
    echo $fnam;
}
```

**EDIT:**

This should work for you to get the file name which calls the function:

```
function file_nameecho(){
    $fnam = basename(debug_backtrace()[0]["file"], '.php'); 
    echo $fnam;
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

So as requested from OP a little explanation to everything :D

1. Why does `__FILE__` return the name where the function is defined?

`__FILE__` is a magic constant and returns the file name.

And a quote from the manual:

> The full path and filename of the file with symlinks resolved. If used inside an include, the name of the included file is returned.

So for more information about magic constant see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

2. What does `debug_backtrace()` do?

`debug_backtrace()` generates a backtrace. So that's why i used it in the function. And you can use `print_r(debug_backtrace());` to see all information about the data backtrace, this is also the way i figured out that in your case it's `[0]["file"]`.

And for more information see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Comment: you really understand my needs, but the function is now returning the main file name that is index, i want it to return other.php file name where I am using this function.

Comment: @UbaidRehman So you want to tell me that you include: `single.php` into `other.php` and this into `index.php` and now you want to get `other` as output? (Called script is: `index.php`, function call in `other.php` and function definition in `single.php`?)

Comment: i have a main file index.php in which i am calling single.php and other.php just below single.php with include function, now i have written the function in single.php but want to use it in other.php where i want the function to return the other.php file name --- consider my single.php file containing general function which i want to call in other files.

Comment: You rocks buddy, but can you please do another edit, explain why basename(__FILE__, '.php'); is not flexible php call ? usually we manage a different file for our function's to work neat and clean and call them when ever we need ? and can you please explain a little about your function too, its just a request,  Thank you so much.

Comment: @UbaidRehman You're welcome! Have a nice day :D (Updated the answer with a little explanation)

Comment: Thank you so much. Kind people like you always win the race of hearts.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php
`__FILE__`  The full path and filename of the file with symlinks resolved. If used inside an include, the name of the included file is returned.

Answer (score 0):

The **FILE** variable will always contain the filename of the current file where the variable is being accessed from which in your case is "single.php"

Take a look at the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) for help.

Answer (score 0):

It would show "single",
**FILE** would be single.php,
You can see php **FILE** [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php).

Answer (score 0):

no, it will show you the page where you include the file. 
to call the `function file_nameecho()` you're forced to use `include ('single.php')` in other.php.
when the server loads the page other.php can not run the `__FILE__` a page with another reference

Comment: till now i have used many function that are flexible and change according to the page or data they are getting what so special in in this function that it is bound to return where it written, usually we manage a different file for our function's to work neat and clean.

Comment: __FILE__ The full path and filename of the file with symlinks resolved. If used inside an include, the name of the included file is returned. http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php, that's what the manual says, I do not know if then there is a way around. with __file__ not think we can, with a few other commands probably